# Question on using gspread to retrieve data and update

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, gspread

I have a google spreadsheet that I want to retrieve:
This is how the data appears on google sheet.
'Business' is the first header and the second row 'Name','Age','Fav color' are the second headers.

| Business |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Name | Age | Fav color |
| a1 | b1 | Green |
| a2 | b2 | Green |
| a3 | b3 | Green |

```
import gspread
import pandas as pd
import gspread_dataframe as gd

worksheet = sh.get_worksheet(index[0])
df = pd.DataFrame(final_worksheet.get_all_records())
```

When I get the worksheet, the output shows up as:

| Business |  |
| --- | --- |
| Name | Fav color |
| a1 | Green |
| a2 | Green |
| a3 | Green |

Which isn't what I am looking for.

Question:I am hoping that I can grab the dataframe with Name, Age, Fav color as column headers (without the Business header) and then allow me to insert some values so that the final output (on google spreadsheet) would be:

| Business |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Name | Age | Fav color |
| John | 99 | Blue |
| a1 | b1 | Green |
| a2 | b2 | Green |
| a3 | b3 | Green |

Here is the code that I used to update my spreadsheet:

```
final_updated = updated.append(final_output)
gd.set_with_dataframe(final_worksheet, final_updated)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- When the values from your sheet are retrieved with `final_worksheet.get_all_records()`, the following value is returned

  ```
    [{'': 'Fav color', 'Business': 'Name'}, {'': 'Green', 'Business': 'a1'}, {'': 'Green', 'Business': 'a2'}, {'': 'Green', 'Business': 'a3'}]
  ```

  - I thought that this might be the reason of your issue.
  - In this case, how about creating the dataframe from the slice retrieved with `get_all_values()`?
- About `I am hoping that I can grab the dataframe with Name, Age, Fav color as column headers (without the Business header) and then allow me to insert some values so that the final output (on google spreadsheet) would be:`, in this case, how about using the method of `insert_rows()`? I thought that in this case, the script might be simpler.
- In your script, `worksheet` is declared. But it seems that `final_worksheet` is not declared.

When above points are reflecvted to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script 1:

In this modified script, `df = pd.DataFrame(final_worksheet.get_all_records())` is modified.

From:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(final_worksheet.get_all_records())
```

To:

```
v = final_worksheet.get_all_values()
df = pd.DataFrame(v[2:], columns=v[1])
```

#### Modified script 2:

In this modified script, the row you want to insert is put using the method of `insert_rows()`.

From:

```
worksheet = sh.get_worksheet(index[0])
df = pd.DataFrame(final_worksheet.get_all_records())
```

To:

```
worksheet = sh.get_worksheet(index[0])
worksheet.insert_rows([['John', 99, 'Blue']], row=3, value_input_option='USER_ENTERED')
```

- In this case, the value of `[['John', 99, 'Blue']]` can be directly inserted to the row 3.

#### References:

- [get_all_values](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_all_values()#gspread.models.Worksheet.get_all_values)
- [insert_rows](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=insert%20row#gspread.models.Worksheet.insert_row)